# ng-model value is not getting passed through ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-filter

I am trying to have custom filter to filter date range, have kept the text field for getting the date from user in popver. It's not working, whereas I have another textbox to get name in the header bar and able to get the value in `ng-repeat` for default filter.

What did I miss here?

**Date Field in Popver**

Which is not under any controller, it is in popver

```
  <label class=" item-input">
    <span class="input-label" style="width:50%;font-size:14px;">From Date</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="fromDate"/>
  </label>
```

**HTML - ng-repeat**

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in Items | filter: custname |  filter: applyDateFilter(fromDate, toDate)">
        <div class="row item wrap">
          <div class="col col-95">
            <ion-checkbox ng-model="item.Selected">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-67">
                  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-33 right">
                  <p>{{item.order_date | datetimeFormat }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ion-checkbox>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

**Filter**

```
 .controller("dbController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.applyDateFilter = function(from, to) {
        return function(items, from, to) {
            console.log(items);
            console.log('from '+from);
            console.log('to '+to);
            console.log('fromDate '+$scope.fromDate);
            console.log('toDate '+toDate);

            var result = [];   

            if(from == 0 && to == 0)
              return items;

            if(from != '' && to != ''){
              var df = parseDate(from);
              var dt = parseDate(to);

              for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                  var tf = new Date(items[i].order_date * 1000);
                  if (tf >= df && tf <= dt)  {
                      result.push(items[i]);
                  }
              }
            }            
            return result;
        };
      }; 
  });
```

**Also tried with filter by passing like** *datetime:fromDate:toDate*

```
.filter('datetime', function($filter){
   return function(items, fromDate, toDate){ 
        from = fromDate;
        to = toDate;
        var result = []; 
        if(from == 0 && to == 0)
          return items;
        if(from != '' && to != ''){
          var df = parseDate(from);
          var dt = parseDate(to);
          for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
              var tf = new Date(items[i].order_date * 1000);
              if (tf >= df && tf <= dt)  {
                  result.push(items[i]);
              }
          }
        }            
        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle to check your flow.

Comment: How are you opening your popover? Are you using ui-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

The popover might be creating a different scope so your `ng-model` is getting registered to a different scope.

Try this solution instead:

Create a global controller and apply that on either `<html>` or `<body>` and put something like in it (`<body ng-controller="GlobalController">`):

```
myApp.controller('GlobalController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.globalModels = {};
    // Or use below if you are using ui-bootstrap
    // $scope.globalModels = {};
});
```

Now, change your view:

```
<label class=" item-input">
    <span class="input-label">From Date</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="globalModels.fromDate"/>
</label>
```

Now, when passing it to filter in `ng-repeat`, pass `globalModels.fromDate` instead of just `fromDate`. Do the same for `toDate`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am using ionic. I tried in both $rootScope and $scope but still getting the same. Getting fromDate as undefined, toDate as ''. Tried changing the name also didn't work. Also tried moving the element to directly header instead of popover, no luck.